# How can you draw separate parts a control in different places with WPF?

Tags: wpf, graphics, user-controls, visualbrush

I'm trying to split the drawing of a WPF UserControl onto two separate pages of a custom Paged Panel that I'm writing. I thought of using a VisualBrush to draw bits of the control. Is this the way to go?

I presume I'll also have to put the controls that need to be visually split in an invisible container. Has anyone come across an effective way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done anything like what you are trying to do, but you can try using a VisualBrush to draw to some container (say Rectangle if your pages are rectangular). You can then use a clipping geometry to clip the area of the UserControl you are trying to display in a page.

Good luck!